# Does Alexa for business support Outside US, We planning to add support of Spanish language

Tags: alexa-skills-kit, alexa-voice-service

We do have 1 private skill which does support in the US with English US support.
Skill does link using Lambda in Node.js.
That skill is developed and distributed as a private skill. skill linking and usage have done using Alexa for Business console.
This means all the Alexa devices are configured using "DeviceSetupTool" from Alexa for Business.

Now we wanted to extend existing English skills with Spanish language support as well. Skill is extended for Spanish.

Alexa app does support changing language however Alexa for business does not allow to change Alexa Device language.

1. Dones Alexa for Business support outside the US?
2. How to change the Alexa language to Spanish from Alexa for Business website?

Answer (score 2):

Currently Alexa for Business is not available in Spanish, it’s available in the US East (N. Virginia) and supports Alexa devices running anywhere in the US. Access or use of Alexa for Business or its features may be restricted or limited in countries where Alexa for Business is not currently offered. For more information:
https://aws.amazon.com/alexaforbusiness/

As a developer you can submit feature requests and ideas in our uservoice space via the following link:
https://alexa.uservoice.com/